# framed frame in beamer?

Tags: beamer, framed

Below is an example of the layout I am trying to make for a `beamer` presentation: just a simple rounded black frame in which I could insert some contents (e.g. text or images).

[image]

I have looked at everything (`block` environment, `fancybox` package, ...) and I just cannot find a way to do it. If anyone has a suggestion, it would be great and much appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on which `beamer` theme you want to use, whether this is a plain frame (without title and head-/footline) etc.?

Comment: http://dundeelug.org.uk/lurker/message/20100518.123835.9084b668.pt.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `background` template to add the frame using `TikZ`; a little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw [line width=1mm,rounded corners]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (0.5cm,-0.5cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-0.5cm,0.5cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo, tickz was obviously missing in the list of things I had tried !